# Перезагрузка формы при отправке. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть инпут куда вбивается штрих-код элемента и рядом есть выбор периода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У поля штрих кода нету кнопки (это форма которая отправляется при клике на клавишу Enter).
У формы есть аттрибут onSubmit который вызывают функцию получения данных с базы.

```
                        <Form
                            onSubmit={date =>
                                this.onChangeDate(
                                    date[0],
                                    date[1],
                                    this.state.barcode
                                )
                            }
                            onSubmit={e => {
                                // e.preventDefault()
                            }}
                            style={{
                                marginRight: '15px',
                                maxWidth: '300px',
                                width: '100%'
                            }}>
                            <Input
                                className={'barcode'}
                                type={'text'}
                                style={{
                                    maxWidth: '300px'
                                    // marginRight: "15px"
                                }}
                                placeholder={'Введите штрих-код'}
                            />
                        </Form>
```

При отправке формы работает данная функция

```
    onChangeDate(dateFrom, dateTo, barcode) {
        if (!dateFrom && !dateTo) {
            dateFrom = moment();
            dateTo = moment();
        }
        barcode = document.querySelector('.barcode').value;
        localStorage.setItem(
            'date_list',
            `${dateFrom.format()}zzz${dateTo.format()}`
        );
        this.getList(
            dateFrom.format(DATE_FORMAT),
            dateTo.format(DATE_FORMAT),
            barcode
        );
        this.setState({
            dateFrom,
            dateTo,
            barcode
        });
    }
```

Мне надо сделать чтобы при отправке формы функция срабатывала но страница не перезагружалась.
Как это сделать? Если сбросить event, то форма вообще не отправляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в *React* нельзя вешать обработчики *DOM* событий на компоненте при его использовании. все методы/свойства, которые Вы задаете в компоненте (в Вашем случае это `onSubmit` и `style`), передаются в компонент `<Form>` **исключительно как props-ы**.

таким образом, Ваша страница перезагружается, потому что у Вас (скорее всего) компонент `<Form />` содержит в себе нативную `<form>`, которая и перезагружает страницу. и у этой `<form>` не задан ни один обработчик события на `onSubmit`.

---

решение: внутри компонента `<Form>` получите Ваш `this.props.onSubmit` (которые Вы передаете в `<Form />` через **props**) и повесьте этот **props** как обработчик для нативной `<form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>`. и не забудьте добавить `e.preventDefault()`